# Is it possible to render hair in Cycles, other parts in Eevee, and then do compositing?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I try to render eyes and hair in Cycles then render face and the rest of the scene like room and light source in Eevee. After that, I try to use the compositor to connect the two render layers in mix node and alpha over but the result is not ok.

How do I make the eyes go behind the eye socket and the hair go behind the head?

There are only 3 objects (head, eyes, and hair). I heard about *Cryptomatte* but can't find the way to do it.

Comment: I am mostly had success with crypto mate with experimentation, and looking at the output images it gave. Seems to be a case by case basis.

Comment: I think you got the downvote because yes, this is doable, but to address what problems you ran into, we need to see how you did it, and what the inputs and outputs are: the input renders, the compositing nodes, and the output image.

Comment: There are a few questions like https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213395/is-it-possible-to-render-part-of-the-composition-in-eevee-and-other-part-in-cycl. It's basically possible. One technique I read about is to render the models in Cycles & the Environment in Eevee. But I don't think it's a good idea to render parts of the model in different render engines. You can combine them with the Depth/Z-Layer, Math node (Greater Than), and Mix Node. But the issue is when you render the eyes and hair without the head there is no Ambient Occlusion & shadows. The composition looks horrible :-(