# Is it possible to render part of the composition in eevee and other part in cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

guys! I want to render this scene (in a video, rotating the camera around the head and the word) but I made the word following a eevee tutorial and the other parts work better in cycles.

Is there a way to render them separately and then join afterwards?

Thanks in advance!

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

### Sure, use two Scenes

You can specify the render engine for each of your Scene in the first panel of the render panel of the Properties.

[image]

Then in the Render layer node you can specificy the Scene to composite.

[image]

If you have problems in rendering multiple scenes at the same time, visit: [How do I batch render multiple scenes with animation settings?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74086/how-do-i-batch-render-multiple-scenes-with-animation-settings)

Comment: thanks!!! will try to do this!

Comment: Interesting, can I use this method to mix automatically two different layers rendered with two render engines or I need to use the file output node as suggested in the link above and then mix  the two files externally?

Comment: You should be able to mix two different layers rendered with two render engines if everything works. It's common practice for example to grab the volumetric fog from eevee (fast and easy) and composite that on a full cyles shot. The link was just for those who has problematic sets-up.

Comment: This does not seem like an answer. you showed a couple screen shots but did not specify HOW to change the renderer for each. When I change the render to cycles, both view layers change.

Comment: @JBRiley You can change the render engine in the first panel of the render panel of the Properties. You should not use a different View Layer, but rather different Scene (with linked asset and all...). The render engine is indipendent for each Scene.

Comment: @Carlo Thanks. I get it now. much appreciated!